# How to write an handleSubmit function to setState for multiple forms

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to write an handlesubmit function that can change the state for multiple forms. I am having trouble with retrieving the input value and using it in my handlesubmit function. Also when I try to setstate, the values disappear from the table.

```
    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let value = this.element.value;
        this.setState({[event.target.id]: value});
    }
```

```
   <td>
   {this.state.benchMax}
   </td>
   <td>
   {this.state.ohpMax}
   </td>
```

```
<td>
<form id="benchMax" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
<input type="number" ref={el => this.element = el}></input>
<input type="submit" value="Update!"></input>
</form>
</td>
<td>
<form id="ohpMax" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
<input type="number" ref={el => this.element = el}></input>
<input type="submit" value="Update!"></input>
</form>
</td>
```

The results don't display in the table, and the changes aren't tracked.

Comment: hi william, try my solution below and let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, that's not the way you want to construct your forms and receive user-input in a React component.

When creating forms you want to follow this pattern:

```
user input -> record state -> form submit using state-values
```

Try this sandbox and see example below: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-euler-67w40

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    benchMax: null,
    ohpMax: null,
    submittedBenchMax: null,
    submittedOhpMax: null
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      submittedBenchMax: this.state.benchMax,
      submittedOhpMax: this.state.ohpMax
    });
  };

  handleOnChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form id="benchMax" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>Bench</label>
          <input type="number" name="benchMax" onChange={this.handleOnChange} />
          <input type="submit" value="Update!" />
        </form>
        <form id="ohpMax" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>Overhead</label>
          <input type="number" name="ohpMax" onChange={this.handleOnChange} />
          <input type="submit" value="Update!" />
        </form>
        <div>
          <h4>Max</h4>
          <p>Bench: {this.state.submittedBenchMax}</p>
          <p>Overhead: {this.state.submittedOhpMax}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thanks this helped fixed my issues.

Answer (score 2):

HandleChange function,

```
handleChange = event => {
    let value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: value})

    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation()
}
```

HandlSubmit,

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {

  //Your code to read values....

  event.preventDefault()
  event.stopPropagation()
}
```

call handleChange inside `input`

```
<input type="number"  name="name1" value={this.state.name1} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the desired outcome is for the content of the other forms to change on submit, not on change.

Comment: Yea I want the content to change when the submit button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

When you call setState, it also calls the render function, which will reset the values of your input fields. Additionally, the event.target value refers to the form itself, not the input field. Try using an onChange event with your input field.